# Can't create a complex interface for angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I want to get the comments array for each user , but i need to create a interface like in the image.

[image]

I can get everything except this property so in my code I do like this:

```
  personSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  person$: Observable<any> = this.personSubject.asObservable();

getAllPosts(event?) {
    this.authService.getAllPosts().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.allPosts = res.length;
      this.down = res.length;

      this.personSubject.next(res.data.post)

})
}
```

```
*ngFor="let i=index; let post of person$ | async | sortPipe"
```

How i can handle this interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user nested interface like that

```
interface Response {
  data: User;
  status: string;
  length: number;
}

interface User {
  post: Post[];
}

interface Post {
  allComments: Comment[];
  author: Author;
  comments: Comment[];
}

interface Comment {
  commentBody: string;
  userData: {
    photo: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: And how do I use in html ? If i try ```post.comments.userData.photo ``` i get ```userData is not defined and Comment[] doesnt contain such member```

Comment: @Inst1nct `post.comments[0].userData.photo`

Comment: when it's array in the interface - ending with `[]` - then you should give it index 0 or loop over it using `*ngFor`